# Building bundle for web in vite

Tags: javascript, vite

I am trying to move from Webpack to Vite. I am using the library mode, but every time I build it, I get node-based code in the built file. This is what I have so far:

```
import {resolve} from 'path'
import {defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin} from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(({mode}) => {
    return {
        plugins: [splitVendorChunkPlugin()],
        build: {
            emptyOutDir: false,
            minify: mode === "dev" ? false : 'terser',
            target: 'es2015',
            lib: {
                formats: ['cjs'],
                name: 'Spark2',
                entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/app.ts'),
            },
            commonjsOptions: {
                include: [/node_modules/]
            },
            outDir: './static',
            rollupOptions: {
                output: {
                    manualChunks: (id) => {
                        if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
                            return 'vendors';
                        }
                    },
                    entryFileNames: mode === "dev" ? 'js/main.js' : 'js/main.min.js',
                    chunkFileNames: mode === "dev" ? 'js/[name].js' : 'js/[name].min.js',
                    assetFileNames: mode === "dev" ? '[ext]/[name].[ext]' : '[ext]/[name].min.[ext]',
                },
            }
        }
    }
})
```

It builds fine but in the browser, I get an error as:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at vendors.js:70:19
```

Looking into the code, I get a line something similar to `const EMPTY_OBJ = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? Object.freeze({}) : {};`

How should I build the bundle for the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `define` object under `plugins`. Which looks like:

```
// removed for brevity
        plugins: [splitVendorChunkPlugin()],
        define: {
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
        },
// removed for brevity
```

More on this can be found at https://vitejs.dev/config/#environment-variables

Comment: I had a very similar issue with a dependency directly using `process.env` (`@krakenjs/zoid`) and I used a similar solution.

Comment: Hopefully this will be fixed somehow in future because this very feels like hack even the fact it works for me now. I don't understand how I am getting process.env.NODE_ENV references in my bundle, because when I build latest clean vue project there are non references. It would be very costly to find out, I already spend couple of hours but did not succeed :/